# How to Get font descriptors - CapHeight, Ascent, Descent, Flags, ItalicAngle, StemV of TTF Font

Tags: vb6, pdf-generation, truetype, embedded-fonts, ps

I am trying to create my own tool for creating the pdf file. Every thing is going well, Only thing I miss is the font descriptors. Kindly let me know the correct values of capheight, ascent, descent, glag, italic angle from afm/pfa/pfb or any tool available to genrate the same

Answer (score 0):

Fontographer will show those values.  A bit pricey for just collecting statistics.  My copy is old, back when Macromedia owned it.  FontLab does now.  See http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/